# Time synchronizing on Raspberry Pi

Tags: google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi3, ntp, google-cloud-vision

I am getting an error related to time synchronization on Raspberry Pi.The error asks me to check and correct iat and exp values.What are these values and how to correct them?

PS:I googled and found about ntp i used it  to correct the time on raspberry pi but I am getting the same error . I am getting the error while trying to access Google Cloud vision API

Comment: Can you provide more context? Show some code and what you have done so far to correct the issue and what the results were.

I am not even sure how a time sync issue is even related to GCP Vision API.

Comment: This is the detailed error : oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values and use a clock with skew to account for clock differences between systems.

Comment: @YingLi this is how i synchronized the time on raspberry pi as shown in this blog   https://www.victorhurdugaci.com/raspberry-pi-sync-date-and-time

Comment: I don't think this is a time sync issue. You should never have a 60 minute time difference. I don't think you are obtaining the token properly. Could you show up your OAuth code and how you are getting the access token?

Comment: @YingLi I dont know about the Oauth code but this is how  I made my cloud vision api work  .I created a service account  on google cloud downloaded the json key copied it on my rpi  and this is my python code for using the JSON credentials::                                 from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials           credentials=GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    service=discovery.build('vision','v1',credentials=credentials)

Comment: Is there a tutorial you were following? Why are you using application default credential on your Raspberry Pi? Please elaborate more and provide more code in your question (not in the comments) so I can help you better.